# Rules for solitaire card games

Tags: playing-cards, solitaire

I know of [pagat](http://www.pagat.com) for games with multiple players, but is there anything similar for solitaire?  I prefers to play with real cards so I am only looking for the sets of rules.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has [quite a collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_patience_games), and the site you mention also has [a page with further links](https://www.pagat.com/patience/patience.html). You might find more online if you also search for "patience", the more common name for "solitaire" outside North America.

Answer (score 1):

You can find rules of 499 solitaire games at [BVS Solitaire Collection](http://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/).